# Composition, Forwarding and Wrapping

Tags: java, composition

On the subject of "prefer composition over inheritance", my teacher says this:

- composition: the existing class becomes a component of the new one
- forwarding: each instance method in the new class, invokes the corresponding method on the contained instance of the existing class and returns the results
- wrapper: the new class encapsulates the existing one

I don't understand very well this three concepts so I try to write down some code:

```
//Composition is this
Class A{
    public void doSomething(){
        //do some code
    }
}

Class B{
    A a = new A();
    public void doOther(){
        a.doSomething();  //this is forwarding
    }
}
```

And so what is wrapping?

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is not composition.

[Composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) is a "[has-a](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)" relationship between 2 objects, where one object (*the composed object*) is a field member of the other (*the owner*).

Composition would be:

```
class DemoA {
    DemoB b; //composition
}
```

We would say "DemoA is composed of DemoB".

<sub>If the `DemoB` object is still usable when `DemoA` becomes unreachable, we consider `DemoB` to be [aggregated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation). For example, keys can still be used although the keyring may have been destroyed. The keyring will be composed of keys, but does not own them, which expresses aggregation.</sub>

---

Your forwarding example looks fine, although the requirements do say "*return the results*", which may suggest the methods should not be void:

```
class DemoA {
    private DemoB b;

    public int doSomething() {
        return b.doSomething(); //forwarding/delegating
    }
}
```

---

As for wrappers, they encapsulate the behavior of the object, exposing new (and usually more complex) behaviors. An example would be [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), which wraps an `InputStream` to allow you to read `String` objects and more, when `InputStream` is only capable of primitive data.

```
class DemoB {
    public int read() {
        //...Read one int of data
    }
}

class DemoA {
    private DemoB b;

    public DemoA(DemoB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public List<Integer> readUntil(List<Integer> dataList, Supplier<Boolean> condition) {
        while(condition.get())
            dataList.add(b.read());

        return dataList;
    }
}
```

In this example, `DemoA` wraps `DemoB` to expose the `readUntil` behavior, something `DemoB` was incapable of doing.

This is somewhat a silly example, but hopefully expresses the point: Our `DemoB` object cannot perform behavior that we need (*readUntil*), so we wrap it in a type that handles the behavior for us, so we aren't constantly rewriting such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> the existing class becomes a component of the new one

Versus

> the new class encapsulates the existing one

It sounds redundant.

Wrapper and composition convey indeed conceptually the same thing.

In your actual example code :

```
class A{
    public void doSomething(){
        //do some code
    }
}

class B{
    A a = new A();
    public void doOther(){
        a.doSomething();  //this is forwarding
    }
}
```

The `B` class composes a `A` instance as it stores a `A` instance in its state and uses it in the `doOtherMethod()` implementation.
Nevertheless, you perform wrapping/composition but you don't use a dispatching pattern as the invoked methods are not symmetric between the composer and the composed instances. You indeed call `b.doOther()` that calls `a.doSomething()`.

A basic dispatching pattern would look like that :

```
class A{
    public void doSomething(){
        //do some code
    }
}

class B{
    A a = new A();
    public void doSomething(){
        a.doSomething();  //this is forwarding
    }
}
```

Here you call exactly the same method in the composed instance as in the composer instance : the `doSomething()` method.
You can add of course  some other methods in the B class.